# PhpStorm: How to disable PHPCS for Javascript

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, phpcs

PHPCS is checking my JS files on PhpStorm,

I need to disable this feature

I added this line in the file `phpcs.xml.dist` but no luck

```
<exclude-pattern>*\.(inc|css|js)</exclude-pattern>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update for newest PhpStorm (2022.3).

The location to change the checked files is now under `File` | `Settings` | `PHP` | `Quality Tools` and select `PHP_CodeSniffer` or search for `PHP_CodeSniffer`

There is not checkbox anymore, it is now a text input with file extensions separated by commas. In the screenshot I removed js and css extensions which are there by default.

[image]

Answer (score 79):

Finally found it, I had to disable some extensions in PhpStorm config
`File` | `Settings` | `Editor` | `Inspections` > `PHP Code Sniffer Validation`
Or search:
`PHP Code Sniffer Validation`
or
`PHP_CodeSniffer validation`

[image]

There is a related bug though
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-44308

Comment: I found that setting too, but PHPCS still inspects my .js files. Did you do anything else? Do you still have that exclude line in your phpcs.xml.dist?

Comment: I didn't do any additional steps, the line has no effect as far as my tests go. Maybe it's a bug on your phpstorm version. I have 2018.3.2 currently

Comment: I encountered the same issue on another machine but I solved it by updating phpcs. `sudo composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"`